# adding onclick action aswell as hover with jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs

im trying to make the jquery tabs so on hover it changes the tabbed content but on click it takes you to another page? this is what ive got but obviously it doesnt work any help?? cheers!!

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    event: "mouseover"
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#secondary-navigation li a').click(function() {
        var over = '';
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('title'));
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('title'));
        return true;
    }, function() {
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('title'));

    });
});
```